# Trace route UIImageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to draw a route between 2 locations on the image and trace route (not in a mapkit)

how can i do this? Is there any library or framework?

**I want to show a route map between two points.**

Like this:

[image: Trace route between 2 points selected. Start End]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGPath` to store the route. You can use a `CGContext` as your canvas. Draw the image into the context and then draw the path in. You can set colours and line attributes like corner style before drawing the path.

Once you have this you can set it as the content of a layer or save it as a new image to display.

[Path drawing guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101)

---

For the route generation, look at the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), do a little googling, maybe something like [this](http://gabrielhora.tumblr.com/post/5412413107/plug-and-play-a-path-finding-algorithm-in-objective-c).

Comment: The problem is to create the algorithm where the destination user is located and take it to the point selected have any idea?